# trapezoid arrow stretching out of div

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to create very specific trapezoid. So far I had success with creating trapezoid form.

```
.trapezoid {
    margin-top : 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    border-left: 100px solid red;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 100px;
}

.trapezoid:before {
    margin-top : 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    border-left:110px solid gray;
    border-top: 55px solid transparent;
    border-bottom : 55px solid transparent;
    width:0;
    height:110px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    content: "";
    left:3px;
    top:-10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/26f4reue/

But as an end result I want to achieve something like that:

[image]

Any ideas would be welcome.

UPDATE:
https://jsfiddle.net/26f4reue/1/

This seems closer to the what I want. Now I can create second trapezoid with arrow inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using CSS:** (with perspective transforms)

One approach would be to use a pseudo-element which is rotated with perspective like in the below snippet. The lines that extend above and below are created using gradients to make the whole shape area be transparent.

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(gray calc(100% - 100px), transparent calc(100% - 100px));
  background-position: top left;
  background-size: 2px 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
.shape:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 76px;
  width: 50px;
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  left: 0px;
  transform-origin: left 50%;
  transform: perspective(50px) rotateY(15deg);
  padding: 10px 14px 10px 0px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-width: 2px 3px 2px 0px;
  border-left: none;
  background: gray;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
.shape:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: calc(50% - 60px);
  left: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, chocolate, sandybrown);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='shape'></div>
```

If you don't want the shape to be transparent (or the background is not an image/gradient) then you could also do like in the below snippet:

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  border-left: 2px solid gray;
}
.shape:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 76px;
  width: 50px;
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  left: -2px;
  transform-origin: left 50%;
  transform: perspective(50px) rotateY(15deg);
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-width: 15px 20px 15px 0px;
  border-left: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px gray, 2px 0px 0px 1px gray, 0px -2px 0px gray;
  background: gray;
  z-index: 1;
}
.shape:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: calc(50% - 60px);
  left: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='shape'></div>
```

---

**Using SVG:**

Another way would be to use SVG's `path` and `polygon` elements like in the below snippet.

```css
svg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 400px;
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, chocolate, sandybrown);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 50 500' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
  <path d='M2,0 2,150 48,185 48,315 2,350 2,500' stroke='gray' fill='transparent' />
  <polygon points='2,165 38,193 38,307 2,335' fill='gray' />
  <path d='M15,235 30,250 15,265' stroke='white' fill='transparent' stroke-width='4' />
</svg>
```

Comment: Ty for the reply. I will investigate your snippet now as It's seems cleaner than mine. Meanwhile I managed to create something that is closer to what I want.

Comment: @user732456 That's fine. I have also added a SVG version which may help you :)